# How many miles will each brother walk?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Two brothers have a horse which can follow any instruction. Starting at the same time,the two brothers want to go to Boishakhi fair which is $20$ miles away. The horse can carry one brother at any moment. The walking velocity of each brother is $4$ miles per hour. The velocity of horse (with or without any load) is $10$ miles per hour. What is the minimum time in which both brothers will reach the fair? How far would each brother would have walked during this trip?

[image]

Comment: You taking a cue by adding a picture from an earlier “cow” question??

Comment: @Rohan this is kind of hilarious...not exactly sure what I should feel about the 'picture' trend.

Comment: So, if both brothers could both ride at the same time, it would take two hours, so the true solution is greater. If they both walk it takes 5 hours. Without caring about whether it's optimal, can you do better than 5 hours?

Comment: I want to minimize time @Arthur

Comment: I know. But the first step there is to make a suggestion that is better than the worst case. Then, from there, we can see whether we can make it even better, and only then can we hope to find an actual minimum. So, I repeat: don't care whether it's minimal yet, can you find a way to do it in better than five hours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly(*) the optimal solution would have the horse carry one of the brothers for some distance (for time $t_1$), then go back and intercept the other brother (at a times $t_2$) (who has been walking) and carry him for the remaining journey($t_3$), in a way such that everyone arrives at the same time. Then this means the total distance of the journey for the first brother is $10t_1+4t_2+4t_3$, the total distance for the second brother is $4t_1+4t_2+10t_3$, and the total distance for the horse is $10t_1-10t_2+10t_3$. These have to all equal $20$.

Solving these simultaneous equations gives $$t_1=\frac{14}{11}\\t_2=\frac{6}{11}\\t_3=\frac{14}{11}$$
And so the total journey time $T$ is $$T=t_1+t_2+t_3=\frac{34}{11}=3\frac1{11}\approx3.09\text{hrs}$$

---

(*) - This is clear because if the optimal solution had the horse go back and forth more than once, then the journey could be rearranged in the way described above, where the horse only has to come back once, and it would take the same amount of time.

Comment: Thank you . I have learned a lot of concepts from this problem . Many many thanks